# Mobile Push Notification

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

I have been testing with Mobile Push Messages.

1: I registered my android device with App.
2: Send Push Notification

I have noticed that there is a delay of up to 15 minutes to receive the push notification message on my Android Device.

Is there a waiting period which needs to be served once the device registers on App?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a propagation delay from the time your device registers with the Marketing Cloud until the time you may send/receive push messages.  That delay can be up to 15 min.

The delay is discussed on the Attributes, Tags, Subscriber Key and Troubleshooting portions of the documentation, but it is oddly absent from the implementation page.  I will ask documentation to update that page to include information regarding the propagation delay.

Comment: Thank you Bill. Can you please share the link where this is discussed?

Comment: http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/